# How to manage locking at type level instead of global level in C# .NET 4.5+?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have the following implementation of a cached generic repository that relies on C#'s `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` that I want to be thread safe. The cache itself can be locked using a single object, but I do not want to use a single object for repository operations as operation on a repository type should not lock operation on a repository of a different type.

```
public class Lock<T>
{
}

public class CachedRepository<T> : ICachedRepository, IRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
{
    // lock object for cache itself
    private static readonly object CacheLockObject = new object();
    // lock object for operations on a repository of current type
    private static readonly object TypeLock = new Lock<T>();

    private void ThreadSafeCacheAccessAction(Action<IDictionary<int, T>, bool> action = null)
    {
        var dict = MemoryCache.Default.Get(CacheDictKey) as IDictionary<int, T>;

        bool invalidated = false;
        if (dict == null)
        {
            lock (CacheLockObject)
            {
                dict = _modelRepository.AllNoTracking.ToList().Where(item => item.PkId != 0).ToDictionary(item => item.PkId, item => item);
                // cache data init removed to be concise 
                MemoryCache.Default.Add(CacheDictKey, dict, cacheItemPolicy);

                invalidated = true;
            }
        }

        // execute custom action, if one is required
        if (action != null)
        {
            lock (TypeLock)
            {
                action(dict, invalidated);
            }
        }
    }

    // examples requiring locking at type level
    public IQueryable<T> AllNoTracking
    {
        get
        {
            IQueryable<T> ret = null;
            ThreadSafeCacheAccessAction((dict, invalidated) =>
            {
                var cachedItems = GetCachedItems();
                ret = cachedItems.AsQueryable();
            });
            return ret;
        }
    }

    public void Insert(T entity)
    {
        // check that entity is not already in the cache (by identifier)
        ThreadSafeCacheAccessAction((dict, invalidated) =>
        {
            if (dict.ContainsKey(entity.PkId))
                throw new ArgumentException($"Attempted to add an already existing key {entity.PkId}");
        });

        _modelRepository.Insert(entity);
    }

    // many other operations use the same locking mechanism
}
```

**Question:** **is it safe to lock using a typed static instance like I did or should I consider an alternative?**

Comment: yes this is a very common practice.

Comment: @DanielA.White - thanks for the quick answer. I have found a lot of question, answers and articles about avoiding locking on `typeof(T)` or `this`, but could not find the recommended implementation. Most folks seem to lock on a non-generic static instance.

Comment: The lock used for thread-synchronizing some data depends upon the type of data: is it static? object level? shared between objects? thread-local data?

Comment: @I-A-N - cached repositories data is loaded once at application startup (warm-up) and may be changed through various operations. Memory cache instance is clearly static, I would say repository data is also static, but the mechanism used to fetch data requires enumeration, thus one thread must not change anything on a collection while other enumerates it (`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`).

Comment: I always consider it a red flag in a code review.  The names are the problem, suggesting that the programmer has trouble grokking `lock`.  It is completely incapable of "locking a type" or "locking the object", it can only block code.  The object is merely there to keep track of the lock state.  Bit of a design mistake in .NET.  Locking objects is what keeps academia busy with STM (Software Transactional Memory).  Been around for a while, it just can't get to our machines.  Nobody has convincingly proven that it can work, somebody has to write an OS that uses it.

Comment: @HansPassant - I am not that advanced to fully understand your comment, but I usually interpret the object used as lock parameter as a "critical section identifier". Of course, this parameter may lead to trouble if it is something visible outside the class performing the `lock`.